# Imputation of missing data: mice gives erratic results in R

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice

I am running some simple code with the mice function for imputation of missing data, using the library mice.

I run the code with the airquality dataset (base R) without a problem, but when I run the same code using another dataset from base R --mtcars--I am getting an error ("undefined columns selected").  See below:

[image]

[image]

The code as text is the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(mice)

data = airquality
data[4:10,3] = rep(NA,7)
data[1:5,4] = NA

summary(data)

tempData = mice(data,m=5,maxit=50,meth='pmm',seed=500)

data(mtcars)

mtcars[mtcars$am == 1, "am"] = NA

data1 = mtcars[, c(2:11)]

summary(data1)

tempData = mice(data1,m=5,maxit=50,meth='pmm',seed=144)
```

I am confused.  Why the same code works in the former case and then does not work in the latter?

Your advice will be appreciated.

## Edit

Indeed I installed the latest version of Mice from CRAN and the code run without a problem

Comment: Please paste your code as text.

Comment: Your code works for me.

Comment: I can reproduce with `mice` 2.30, but it (seems to) work with `mice` 2.46. Please update your package installation.